# Combining VLOOKUP or MATCH and COUNTIF

Tags: google-sheets

I've been trying (and failing) to work out if it's possible to use a formula to count the "Yes" answers depending on whether there is certain text in a row above....and this certain text is in a data validation list.

For example, I have the sheet1 below and then on sheet2 I have a validation list in cell k1 with "school 1", "school 2" etc. I'm trying to see if it's possible in cell H4 of sheet2 to count the number of "Yes" in row 3 of sheet1 only if the contents of K1 (either "School 1" or "School 2" depending on which I select from the list) appears in row 2 in the same column?

A................B...............C................D

School1.....School2....School1.....School1

Yes............No............Yes.............Yes

I'm not that great with Excel so would really appreciate it if someone could let me know if this just isn't possible!

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Please try:

```
=COUNTIFS(Sheet1!A2:D2,$K$1,Sheet1!A3:D3,"Yes")
```

Comment: That has worked perfectly! Thank you so much - I spent hours trawling through google looking for a solution so I really appreciate your help.